# Remove bottom space of auto text size android

Tags: android

I'm using Autosizing TextViews, but sometimes it has a space line in the bottom of text view. Anyone know this?

[image]

[image]

```
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/colorGrayAlto"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="27sp"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:id="@+id/tvVerse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/azbuka_pro"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="40dp"
        android:textSize="27sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="The follower of the law, even if he can recite only a small portion (of the law), but, having forsaken passion and hatred and foolishness, possesses true knowledge and serenity of mind, he, caring for nothing in this world or that to come, has indeed a share in the priesthood." />
```

Comment: Do share your xml

Comment: @PriyankaRajput I updated

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have defined gravity with

```
 android:gravity="center|top"
```

It sticks the text to top only.
Try to change it as following-

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: Yea. but I want to keep top location and fit bottom. Is there any idea?

Comment: If you are fixing it to the top then there will be space surely in the bottom.

Comment: do you know are there any way else to set autosizing with fit height text?. I must keep design. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorGrayAlto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="27sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:id="@+id/tvVerse"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/azbuka_pro"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="40dp"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            tools:text="The follower of the law, even if he can recite only a small portion (of the law), but, having forsaken passion and hatred and foolishness, possesses true knowledge and serenity of mind, he, caring for nothing in this world or that to come, has indeed a share in the priesthood." />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it still same result

Comment: try after change from this android:gravity="center|top" to android:gravity="center"  this in TextView.